# Understanding dictionary assignment with tuple and list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a python beginner and I recently learned about dictionary assignment.
Here's what I am attempting

```
my_list = [[1, 4], [2, 2],[5,1]]
lists = dict(my_list)
print(lists)   # Prints {1:4,2:2,5:1}

my_list = [(1, 4), (2, 2),(5,1)]
lists = dict(my_list)
print(lists)   # Prints {1:4,2:2,5:1}

my_list = [[1, 4], (2, 2),{5,1}]
lists = dict(my_list)
print(lists)   # Prints {1:5,2:2}
```

I am unable to explain why we are getting this weird answer in example 3.
Kindly help and explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{5, 1}` is a `set` and, as such, inherently unordered. It is, somewhat depending on your Python implementation, unpredictably iterated as either `1->5` or `5->1`. If you catch the first case, your `dict` instantiation is equivalent to:

```
lists = dict([(1, 4), (2, 2), (1, 5)])
```

or, even more verbose and obvious

```
lists = {}
lists[1] = 4
lists[2] = 2
lists[1] = 5  # overrides first binding of 1
```

Since there can be no duplicate keys in a `dict`, the last key binding for a repeated key "wins".

Comment: Does this mean, there is a chance that i may get ans - {1:4,2:2,5:1}

Comment: @Avataar17, Yes, it does. But you shouldn't assume `set` gives any specific order.

Comment: Theoretically, yes. Practically, the common CPython implementation `set` will produce `ints` (small positive ones in particular) in sorted order rather consistently.